# FPDF error: Could not include font definition: Works offline but not online

Tags: php, fonts, fpdf

I have a similar problem to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459039/fpdf-error-could-not-include-font-definition-file-in-php):"FDPDF error: Could not include font definition`. However, the error only occurs on my live server - my development server running XAMPP has no problems, so I assume there is nothing wrong with my code.

The directory structure on both servers is identical and I have ensured permission is given to the `/font` folder. I have put the font folder in every location relative to the pdf page's folder possible. What could be causing the problem?

Comment: It should be `/fonts`, with an "s" if I'm right.

Comment: The enviroment are exactly a copy of each other?

Comment: No, it's '/font' - I just extracted it from the FPDF download zip. @MarcoMura Yes, it works flawlessly on my dev server. Only when I upload it to the live server does the error occur, although the directory structure and pathing is identical.

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved this - I was using a custom font, with a camel cased file name. Even though the case was correct in my PHP, I tried changing both the file name and the reference to lower case and it now works. Presumably a difference in Windows and Unix.

Comment: Unix is case sensitive, Windows is case insensitive. This has caught me with some other things to do with files as well