# FPDF - No font has been set

Tags: php, fpdf

i got this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: No font has been set
```

my code

```
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','font/');
require('fpdf.php');
```

my php file is in the same folder than fpdf.php

Any idea  ? thank you

Comment: Simular question like that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459039/fpdf-error-could-not-include-font-definition-file-in-php

Comment: I already saw this post want it doesn't solve the error

Answer (score 1):

Insert this in your file:

```
 $pdf->SetFont('helvetica','',10);
```